# SQL Server 2012 - Common Table Expression (CTE) returning more rows than it should

Tags: sql-server-2012, cte, recursive

## [CTE SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ecbae/2)

I have one lifetable with 121 rows and 3 columns (age, male and female). I have to fetch all the 121 rows considering the gender. If the gender is "Male" I fetch the column "Male" from lifetable as qx and the column "Female" as qy and vice-versa.

However, I need to calculate a fourth column, vx, whose value starts with 1 and the subsequent values are calculated as follows, using the previous value of vx itself:

```
vx = (vx / (1 - @interestRate)^age)
```

The age always goes from 0 to 120, incremented by one each step.

I am [not well versed with CTEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262313/update-1-how-to-refer-to-the-previous-value-of-a-computed-column-in-sql-serve/262339#262339), therefore, I'm taking baby steps to accomplish my tasks with this new method to me. and I need help.

When I try to calculate vx, the query returns 7381 instead of 121.

Here is my CTE:

```
DECLARE @gender VARCHAR(10) = 'MALE'
DECLARE @interestRate NUMERIC(7, 5) = 0.0354

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        lt.Age,
        CASE
            WHEN @gender = 'MALE' THEN
                lt.Male
            ELSE
                lt.Female
        END AS qx,
        CASE
            WHEN @gender = 'MALE' THEN
                lt.Female
            ELSE
                lt.Male
        END AS qy,
        CAST(1.0 AS NUMERIC(7, 5)) AS vx
    FROM LifeTable AS lt

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        cte.Age + 1,
        cte.qx,
        cte.qy,
        CAST((vx / (1 + @interestRate)) AS NUMERIC(7, 5)) AS vx
    FROM cte

    WHERE cte.Age < 120

) SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRows FROM cte OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

I am a little bit tired for I spent my afternoon trying to solve this, it's already night, so my question might be taken as low effort, but I really need your help to see where I am making mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the anchor in the CTE returns all 120 rows instead of a single anchor row. Try this code instead, notice the WHERE clause in the CTE SELECT:

```
DECLARE @gender VARCHAR(10) = 'MALE'
DECLARE @interestRate NUMERIC(7, 5) = 0.0354

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        lt.Age,
        CASE
            WHEN @gender = 'MALE' THEN
                lt.Male
            ELSE
                lt.Female
        END AS qx,
        CASE
            WHEN @gender = 'MALE' THEN
                lt.Female
            ELSE
                lt.Male
        END AS qy,
        CAST(1.0 AS NUMERIC(7, 5)) AS vx
    FROM LifeTable AS lt
    WHERE Age = 1
    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        cte.Age + 1,
        cte.qx,
        cte.qy,
        CAST((vx / (1 + @interestRate)) AS NUMERIC(7, 5)) AS vx
    FROM cte

    WHERE cte.Age < 120

) SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRows FROM cte OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: You are right! Thank you very, @HandyD!

Comment: It should be 1 - @interestRate